# CMake find protobuf compiled from source

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I am trying to build a project that depends on Google Protocol Buffers compiled from source. My project should be platform independent and also should support cross-compilation, which is the reason that i prefer to use a locally built protobuf. However I would prefer not to include the whole library as a subproject as it would take too much to build.

My simplified CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(sample-protobuf)

# find a boost install with the libraries filesystem and system
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(sample
    ${SOURCES}
)
target_link_libraries(sample
    PRIVATE
        protobuf::libprotobuf
)
```

I invoke CMake on Linux as:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/built/protobuf/ ..
```

but it does not find the library and I get the following message:

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Protobuf" with any
  of the following names:

    ProtobufConfig.cmake
    protobuf-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Protobuf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Protobuf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Protobuf" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

On Windows this procedure works.
I built the library on Linux using the suggested approach, which is not with CMake but with autotools.

What should I do differently?

Comment: Strange. CMake has shipped [FindProtobuf.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindProtobuf.html) module, which should be used for find `Protobuf` instead of configuration file (`ProtobufConfig.cmake`). Don't you have this module suddenly deleted? CMake modules location is `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/` or similar.

Comment: @Tsyvarev protobuf can't be in /usr/... because giulatona explicitly doesn't want to install protobuf systemwide (installing systemwide never makes sense when you regularly do cross-compilation).

Comment: File `FindProtobuf.cmake` is **shipped with CMake**, not with a protobuf.

Comment: Confirm that the path you are specifying contains a protobuf config file (cd /path/to/built/protobuf/; find . -name "\*.cmake").  You should see something like: ./cmake/protobuf-config.cmake (possibly with .in suffix).  You should also see a module file (./cmake/protobuf-module.cmake).   If all are found, I would suggest defining the Protobuf_DIR directly in your CMakeLists.txt until you get things working, then bring out any definitions to the commandline.

Answer (score -3):

```
cd protobuf/cmake
mkdir build
cd build
cmake....
make...
sudo make install
```

Comment: The quality of your answer would be more evident were you to explain the steps you're suggesting.